# AngularJS: Get value from childController to parentController

Tags: angularjs, forms

I can not get a value in my form, I have 2 controllers and I'm trying to print the value of a dropdownlist which is inside a second controller (CtrlB). How can I get the value from this child controller on my parent controller? Everything is working very good, the render with the values of my dropdownlist, my form, my validations, except the value that get the $scope.dropdownlist. Any help?

**my CtrlA controller**

```
$scope.register = function (isValid) {

    name = $scope.name; // works!
    documentType = $scope.dropdownlist; // Got undefined :(
}
```

**my directive**

```
<select ng-model="dropdownlist" <!-- I can not get this value inside my CtrlA controller-->
        ng-options="x.description for x in types">
</select>
```

**my form**

```
    <form role="form"
            name="nonClientRegisterForm"
            ng-submit="register(nonClientRegisterForm.$valid);"
            novalidate>

            <div class="form-group" 
                ng-class="{ 'has-error' : nonClientRegisterForm.name.$invalid && !nonClientRegisterForm.name.$pristine }">

                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        name="firstinput"
                        ng-model="firstinput" 
                        class="form-control"
                        required />
            </div>

            <div>
                <!-- This component has its own controller that fills this dropdownlist -->
                <dropdownlist ng-controller="CtrlB"></dropdownlist>
            </div>

            <span ng-show="
                (nonClientRegisterForm.name.$invalid && 
                !nonClientRegisterForm.name.$pristine)"
class="help-block">
                Debes completar todos los campos.
            </span>

            <button 
                type="submit" 
                ng-disabled="nonClientRegisterForm.$invalid">
                continuar
            </button>                        
        </div>                    
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: wouldn't $scope essentially be looking within each controllers 'scope' ?   You could use rootScope, or just bundle everything into one controller.   $rootScope.otherVar = "This can be accessed in all controllers";

Comment: can you provide a bit more code here?  It appears that you have created a custom directive `dropdownlist`, but it's not obvious how this directive works.  It is abnormal for `ng-controller` to be used on a custom directive in this way; normally a directive would have it's controller internally defined, and the directive definition would have variables defined for data exchange.  The design you are demonstrating here seems to indicate that the directive itself could be refactored.

Comment: @MichaelMeritt while `$rootScope` is indeed accessible to all controllers, that's not what it was designed to do, and using `$rootScope` in this manner is just another indication that there is code that should probably be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

you should use $rootscope to get values from child controller to parent controller.

```
$scope.register = function (isValid) {
name = $scope.name; 
documentType = $rootscope.dropdownlist;}

  function CtrlB($scope) {
$rootscope.dropdownlist="A";}
```

Comment: This will work, but as I mentioned previously in the comments, this is an anti-pattern.  The original directive in the question isn't written properly, and trying to fix it by using `$rootScope` not only means there is still a broken component that hasn't been fixed, it also means you are using a core service for something other than what it was intended for.